# How to map property of type repeated of proto file to list property of C# class using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0, grpc-dotnet

I have a proto file with following details:

**TestGRPC.proto:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyGRPC";

package MyApi;

service Author {
  rpc GetArticles (ArticleRequest) returns (ArticleResponse);
}

message ArticleRequest {
  int32 articleId = 1;
  int32 countryId = 2;
  string userCookieId = 3;
}

message ArticleResponse {
   int32 ArticleId = 1; 
   string Title = 2;    
   repeated TaxTagsResponse RelatedTaxTags = 3; 
}

message TaxTagsResponse{
    int32 TaxTagId = 1;
    string DisplayName = 2;
}
```

This is used in a asp.net core 3.1 gRPC client project which has DTO classes with following structure:

```
public class ArticleDTO
{
    public int ArticleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<TaxTagsDTO> RelatedTaxTags
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TaxTagsDTO
{
    public int? TaxTagId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? ParentTagId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? CountryId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty("displayname")]
    [RegularExpression(Constants.GeneralStringRegularExpression)]
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? LanguageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<CountryDTO> RelatedCountries
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ArticleResponse, ArticleDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.RelatedTaxTags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RelatedTaxTags));
    }
}

public class ArticleService : IArticleService
{
    private readonly IOptions<UrlsConfig> _appSettings;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILogger<ArticleService> _logger;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ArticleService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<UrlsConfig> appSettings, ILogger<ArticleService> logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
    }

    public async Task<ArticleDTO> GetArticleAsync(int articleId, int countryId, string userCookieId)
    {
        return await GrpcCallerService.CallService(_appSettings.Value.GrpcAuthor, async channel =>
        {
            var client = new AuthorGRPC.Author.AuthorClient(channel);
            var response = await client.GetArticlesAsync(new ArticleRequest{ArticleId = articleId, CountryId = countryId, UserCookieId = userCookieId});
            _logger.LogDebug("grpc response {@response}", response);
            var articleResponse = _mapper.Map<ArticleDTO>(response);
            return articleResponse;
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue.

Comment: Note: if you use protobuf-net.Grpc you don't *need* to use protoc generated types *at all* - it works directly on code-first POCOs; you don't *need* to use any tooling, but if you want to know what that would look like with protobuf-net.Grpc: put your .proto in here: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ (emphasis: it could work entirely with your hand written types, as long as you tell it the numbers via the attributes)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for your response. Can you please help me with some code example as reference in context to my issue

Comment: It isn't clear tome what exactly you want me to illustrate, that isn't clear simply by dropping the proto schema into the generator I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I updated the MappingProfile with the following code and it worked for me now :)

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<TaxTagsResponse, TaxTagsDTO>();
            CreateMap<ArticleResponse, ArticleDTO>();                
        }
    }
```